# WordCloud stopwords not functioning correctly

Tags: python, nlp, word-cloud

WordCloud's stopwords do not stop the stopwords from appearing in the cloud. The words are inside the `stop_words` list passed into the `wc` object, but yet stopwords like 'it' still appear in the output:

```
'it' in wc.stopwords # -----> shows True

from wordcloud import WordCloud
wc = WordCloud(stopwords = stop_words, background_color="white", colormap="Dark2",
               max_font_size=150, random_state=42)


%%time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [18, 9]

names = names

for index, pres in enumerate(data.columns):
  wc.generate(data_clean.speech[pres])

  plt.subplot(3, 4, index+1)
  plt.imshow(wc, interpolation='bilinear')
  plt.title(names[index], color='white', size=16)
plt.show()
```

I expect not to see the word 'it' in the cloud ...

Comment: Welcome to SO. First, since your question is primarily about Python (and not deep-learning), you must tag it [tag:python] otherwise the Python community here will never see it. Second, we need you to post a reproducible example ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). We don't need your plot or plotting code, but we do need to see the contents of `wc = WordCloud(...)`, so please edit the question to post them.

Comment: Also you haven't supplied `data`,`data.columns`, `data_clean.speech[pres]` so your code isn't reproducible and we can't see your output or verify your issue. Please delete all unnecessary plotting code, add some minimal data to illustrate your issue. (Don't even need your document, you should be able to repro on sample data like *"The cat sat on the mat"*)

Comment: Here's the [doc for `wordcloud.WordCloud`](https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html#wordcloud.WordCloud). Btw it says `stopwords` should be a **set** of strings (not a list?)

Comment: You also need to show us your `stop_words` list. Try using `set(stop_words)` too, does that work?